# Get link button text in gridview from delete button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with paging function.

the code below is my aspx code for gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  GridLines="None" Width="768px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging" >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SAP No" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="10%"> 
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"
                        Text='<%#Eval("SAPNO") %>' runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="PARTNO" HeaderText="Part No" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="10%">  
             </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PARTDESC" HeaderText="Description" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="20%"> 
             </asp:BoundField>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="MINQTY" HeaderText="Min Qty" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="5%">  
             </asp:BoundField>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="QOH" HeaderText="QOH" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="5%">  
             </asp:BoundField>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="CATEGORY" HeaderText="Category" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="20%">  
             </asp:BoundField>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="EQUIPMENT" HeaderText="Equipment" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="20%">  
             </asp:BoundField>
             <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" ButtonType="Image" DeleteImageUrl="Image/delete.JPG" ControlStyle-Height="20px" ControlStyle-Width="50px" HeaderText="Delete">
    <HeaderStyle Width="10%" HorizontalAlign="Left" /></asp:CommandField>
        </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />

    <PagerSettings  Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" FirstPageText="<--" PreviousPageText="<" NextPageText=">"  LastPageText="-->" />
     <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

At the back end code, i tried to retrieve the first column and specific rows but it throw me empty. the code below is how i retrieve.

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
string sapNo1 = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text; 
string partNo = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text; 
string partDesc = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text;
```

I try to show all the value for sapNo1, it throw me blank but for partNo it will show the data in the gridview.

anyone has any idea about this?
I am really appreciate your help and comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your first column is a linkbutton so retrieve that as it is then find the value.

```
string sapNo1 = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text; // wrong code to retrieve data from linkbutton in a gridview
```

Modify this as :

```
LinkButton linkbtn =(LinkButton)GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("LinkButton1");
string sapNo1 = linkbtn.Text;
```

or

```
string sapNo1 =(GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("LinkButton1") as LinkButton).Text;
```

Comment: omg! the first answer you posted is helpful! really thanks for your help! now I understand why I couldn't get it :)

Comment: You're welcome; it has been my pleasure helping you out!

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the controls properties present inside `TemplateField` like that, you need to find the control like this:-

```
LinkButton LinkButton1 = (LinkButton)GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0]
                                              .FindControl("LinkButton1");
```

After this you can simply fetch the properties of this control:-

```
string sapNo1 = LinkButton1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the link button description by the below code

```
protected void Link_Button_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            LinkButton button = (LinkButton)sender;
            string name = button.ToString();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lbl_message.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```